# how to validate dates scenarios in array List containing different items with start date and end date

Tags: java, spring, date

I am working on a validation scenario where an Array List will have different courses with start date and end date
like : `List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<>();`

lets suppose `courseList` has 10 items

Now I have to validate that `startDate` of 2nd course can not be before `endDate` of first course.
Basically 2 courses can not run concurrently.

What could be the most efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: Looks like an interval problem to me

Comment: Show the code you have so far. Anyway, loop through the list and check `courseList.get(i).getEndDate().isBefore(courseList.get(i+1).getStartDate())` ...